# ImagickPixel::__construct not implemented

Tags: php, ubuntu, imagick, multi-factor-authentication

Imagick has been implemented for generating a QRcode when enabling MFA. When trying to visit the page to enable MFA this error appears:

> **500** ImagickPixel::__construct not implemented

Here is some more info:

- PHP 7.3 is in use
- php7.3-imagick has been installed
- Ubuntu 18.04 Server
- `extension=imagick.so` has been added to /etc/php/7.3/apache2/php.ini
- The apache server has been restarted after changes
- php7.3-fpm also has been restarted
- When running `php -m | grep imagick` imagick does appear

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 0):

The issue has been resolved, Laravel upgrade fixed the error!

Comment: Please specify the version you used for fixing. Ideally explain why, or quote from the changelog.